# Make does not generate debug symbols

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have a Makefile as :

```
CC = g++

#SNAP DEFINITIONS
SNAP = Snap-2.3
SNAPCORE = $(SNAP)/snap-core
GLIB = $(SNAP)/glib-core
CPPFLAGS += -I $(GLIB) -I $(SNAPCORE)

pagerank_debug.o: pagerank.cpp 
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c pagerank.cpp -o pagerank_debug.o

pagerank.o: pagerank.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c pagerank.cpp

pr_debug: pagerank_debug.o $(SNAPCORE)/Snap.o
    $(CC) -g pagerank_debug.o $(SNAPCORE)/Snap.o -o prd

pr: pagerank.o $(SNAPCORE)/Snap.o
    $(CC) pagerank.o $(SNAPCORE)/Snap.o -o pr

.PHONY: clean 
clean: 
    rm *.o prd
```

On executing `make pr_debug`, the code is compiled as :

```
g++ -I Snap-2.3/glib-core -I Snap-2.3/snap-core -c pagerank.cpp -o pagerank_debug.o
g++ -g pagerank_debug.o Snap-2.3/snap-core/Snap.o -o prd
```

I do not see any debug symbols. What could be a potential issue?

Updated Makefile( Still does not work )

```
#SNAP DEFINITIONS
SNAP = /Users/myth/Snap-2.3
SNAPCORE = $(SNAP)/snap-core
GLIB = $(SNAP)/glib-core
INCLUDE += -I $(SNAPCORE) -I $(GLIB) 
CPPFLAGS += -c -g -Wall

pagerank_debug: pagerank_undirected.cpp 
        g++ $(INCLUDE) $(CPPFLAGS) pagerank_undirected.cpp -o pagerank_undirected.o

pr_debug: pagerank_debug
        g++ -g pagerank_undirected.o $(SNAPCORE)/Snap.o -o pru

.PHONY: clean all

all: pr_debug
clean: 
    rm *.o pru
```

Comment: `-g` does nothing for linking, you need to pass the flag during compiling.

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully : "$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -g pagerank.cpp -o pagerank_debug.o". If I just give a "-g" flag without a "-c", I get a : Undefined Symbol error as the compiler cannot find SNAP library.

Comment: What does  `g++ -ISnap-2.3/glib-core -ISnap-2.3/snap-core -g -c pagerank.cpp -o pagerank_debug.o; objdump -g pagerank_debug.o` tell you?

Comment: I am running on 64bit OSX machine and I guess objdump is only available on 32bit OSX machines from external sources.

Comment: How are you determining if you have debug symbols or not?

Comment: OSX creates :  "a".out.dSYM file in the same directory which has debug symbols.

Comment: Huh, ok my bad, it seems like you need to provide the -g flag both when compiling **and** linking on OSX.

Comment: Does not solve the problem. :(

Comment: Was `Snap-2.3/snap-core/Snap.o` compiled with the `-g` flag?

Comment: I don't think it was.

Answer (score 0):

`-g` flag should be added when compiling, so add it to `CPPFLAGS`:

```
CPPFLAGS += -I $(GLIB) -I $(SNAPCORE) -g
```